# What is meant by 4 –12% or 8% SDS-PAGE?

Tags: biochemistry, lab-techniques, gel-electrophoresis, western-blot, sds-page

I am reading a journal [paper](https://www.jneurosci.org/content/jneuro/33/42/16828.full.pdf) and I am looking at the materials and methods section. Regarding the Western blot method in the paper, I have come across the following statement:

> Proteins were separated by 4 –12% or 8% SDS-PAGE and electroblotted to
> nitrocellulose transfer membrane.

I am not sure what is meant by '4-12% or 8% SDS-PAGE' in the above statement. Do the percentage values refer to the percentage of acrylamide in the gel? Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do the percentage values refer to the percentage of acrylamide in the gel?

Yes. The 8% gel is 8 g acrylamide per 100 mL. The “4-12%” gel is a gradient gel, which are useful for separating proteins over a large range of sizes. Read more about the uses and formulations of gradient gels [here](https://bitesizebio.com/47184/gradient-gels/).